# OBJ Exporting MakeHuman Character from Blender 2.8 with Textures as OBJ file - NOT .FBX

Tags: materials, export

1) Imported MakeHuman Character - Successful
2) Able to see all the Hair, Skin, Clothes, Shoes in Blender
3) Trying to Export as OBJ file (With Write Materials, Copy chosen) --> When uploading this OBJ file to Mixamo.com for Rigging, it looses all the material.

Note: I am able to export the Makehuman character directly as OBJ and upload to Mixamo with textures. But when i bring it to Blender to edit clothes, the export does not come with material file name in the MTL file and looses its material.

Please help.
[image: Mixamo Image]
[image: Blender Image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Texture_maps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: My MTL file after export looks like this: # Blender MTL File: 'Gadothgajan.blend'
# Material Count: 2

newmtl Gadoth_Skin
Ns 506.250000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.0 0.0 0.0
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl None
Ns 500
Ka 0.8 0.8 0.8
Kd 0.8 0.8 0.8
Ks 0.8 0.8 0.8
d 1
illum 2

Comment: It did not have the File Name i was expecting!

Comment: OBJ file export, not an FBX file export

Comment: Consider uploading the blend file for us to take a look at.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute! That is what I was talking about in my answer. Your Specular Value is through the roof. Set Ks in your MTL file to KS 0 0 0 and you should be able to see your texture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading a OBJ to mixamo, you need to supply all textures as image files together with the mesh, packed in a ZIP file.

As an example, I have textured a cube. This Cube exports out as 3 files:

1. **the Mesh** as the OBJ file
2. **the Material Manifest** as the MTL file
3. **the Texture** as a TIF file. If you have other textures on your model, those will come out as their respective formats.

[image: MTL File in Text Editor and Textures and Files to be Imported to Mixamo]

If you open your MTL file with a text editor, you can see the path the texture is supposed to be located at in relation to the OBJ file. In my example, there is no folder, just the name of the file, which indicated that the texture is supposed to be on the same level in the file folder hierarchy than the OBJ file.

ZIP these 3 files together and upload them to mixamo.

[image: Mixamo Upload of Cube]

Tip: Blender by default has a very high Specular Default Value. This will make your object very reflective, to the point where you will no longer be able to see the applied materials and textures in mixamo. You can turn down Specularity in Blender, or, if like me you constantly forget, do it in the MTL file. 
Change the Specular Value (Ks) to something much lower, like `Ks 0 0 0`

[All MTL file parameters explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Material_template_library)

You have no materials applied to your meshes. Select any mesh part, go to the Properties Window, select the Materials Tab and add a new Material Slot. Then select a material from the dropdown list, like the "Skinny" material that you have created. If your image texture is still in place, it will now show up in the preview and you should be good to go.

[image: Assigning Material]

Comment: Ben, I am with you on the upload to Mixamo. Trouble is my .mtl file out of blender do not have the file name in it. So not able to refer the png file i have. "# Blender MTL File: 'Gadothgajan.blend'
# Material Count: 2

newmtl Material
Ns 506.250000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.0 0.0 0.0
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl None
Ns 500
Ka 0.8 0.8 0.8
Kd 0.8 0.8 0.8
Ks 0.8 0.8 0.8
d 1
illum 2"

Comment: That would suggest your textures are not correctly assigned. Time to upload your blend file and add it to your question. You can do that here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6053" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6053/)

Comment: I added the Material Assigning Process to the answer.

Comment: Ben, I have uploaded the latest blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6054" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6054/).  <br/> I tried few things, when i had the Principled BSDF, i get the file name in the MTL file plus the copy of the file when exporting. When i used Diffuse BSDF, i dont get the file name in the MTL file.  <br/> Sorry for being a pain, i am new to Blender and struggling with this for past 1 month. It was so relieving and happy that you are interacting and am able to discuss.  <br/> In either case, i loose material.

Comment: The only way in which I can get the OBJ export to work from 2.8 at the moment is by manually saving the image textures as PNG files and then adding their names in the MTL file with the map_Kd parameter. It is not convenient, but it works. If you can use 2.79 with Blender Internal Renderer, you do not have to go through all this manual work. The export works from there.

Comment: Ben, I did the following:
1) In Blender 2.8, I updated the image file name manually after the map_Kd parameter 2) Also reduced the Ks value manually to 0 0 0 It worked and am able to see the skin in Mixamo. [![Updated OBJ file uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt3uR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt3uR.png)